# Must delete massive inadvertent checkin from remote git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

My situation is that a massive, 2GB file has been inadvertently pushed to our remote git repo on Azure DevOps.  I noticed this when reviewing the pull request.

I cannot have a file that big in my repo and need to delete it.  From the history as well.  I don't want someone cloning the repo to pull down a pointless 2 GB file

The checkin is still on a branch.  It has not been merged to the master.  But it is on the remote repo

As long as nobody else is using this branch, is it safe for my user to do a git reset on this branch?  I'm told that a git revert will not delete the file from the history and that I need a git reset.

Is this my path to a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm told that a git revert will not delete the file from the history and that I need a git reset. Is this my path to a fix?

Mostly, yes. The user should rewrite their branch such that the large file no longer exists in any commit on that branch. There are a few different ways to do this, and `reset` is one of them. Presumably their are other changes on the branch that the user still needs, so you can make a commit that deletes the file, and then interactive rebase and squash the delete commit into the commit that added the file. Regardless of what method you use to rewrite the branch, you'll need to simply force push that branch out to update the PR.

Note there are some caveats here:

1. Once the repo doesn't have any refs (e.g. branches, tags, etc.) pointing to the big bad commit, all *new* clones won't contain the large file, but it won't instantly disappear from all the existing copies of the repo that already fetched that commit. It will eventually get garbage collected, but after the branch is force pushed I would recommend figuring out the exact command(s) you need to either force a `gc` or prune that commit from your repo, test it, and share the instructions with the rest of your users.
2. Azure DevOps might never delete that commit, even if it has been removed from all local copies of the repo. In other words, the commit will be orphaned on the server, probably forever. If you know the commit ID, or any historical PR (even abandoned) that referenced it, you will still be able to navigate to, and access the original commit. From there you could even "revive" the commit by creating a remote branch at that commit, which would make the file reappear in fetches and clones. The fact that this capability exists normally shouldn't be a concern, but if the fact that the file is never truly deleted from the remote server is a problem for you, you may have to involve MS support to see if they can somehow prune that commit from the history. (Note whether this is possible may also depend on whether you're using AzDO Server or Services.)

**Tip:** In AzureDevOps, under Project Settings->Repositories, there are options for the entire system and also each individual repo, where you can set the Maximum file size that can be pushed. I recommend you enable that setting to a sensible option. I would also recommend setting it a little too low rather than too high, since you can temporarily give people permission to override policies in the rare instance they need to purposefully push something above the limit. (Of course, this assumes it will be rare enough that an admin giving permission temporarily won't be a bottleneck or annoyance to developers.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tip on the max-file-size policy thing.  That's definitely going into effect.  As it turns out, no amount of resetting would make Azure Devops actually reset it.  Git would report that it was successful but nothing would change.  We suspect it because of the outstanding pull request because we were able to do resets on another test repos in Devops that we tried first.  Finally we resorted to having the developer completely delete his branch, both locally and remotely and the repos size went back down to 70 MB.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe the reset *should* have worked too, as long as it was force pushed afterwards. The existence of a PR shouldn't lock the ref for new *clones*. But yeah, deleting the branch also works.

Comment: @Joe can you clarify how you confirmed  the remote repo size went back down?

Comment: Well, I cloned the repo before we deleted the branch and it was about 2 GB in size and took a couple minutes to pull.  Then after we deleted the branch I cloned again and the repo size was 70 MB and pulled instantly...

Comment: @Joe OK. Any chance you hadn't force pushed out the branch after the reset (which I assume was back to a commit before the bad one)? That could explain why it didn't have an effect.

Comment: @Joe I just realized you never said the remote repo size went down too. I misread your comment. ;) The local clone size was reduced, and I think that's the best you can do. (And really what matters most.)

Comment: We did the reset and then tried pushing everything multiple times.  The exact same reset process that worked on a test Azure Devops Repo failed to work on this one.  It simply made no changes.  The history window remained the same

The remote repo *did* get reduced in size after we deleted the remote branch though.  I know this because because before deleting the remote branch, cloning it fresh pulled 2 GB of data.  After deleting the remote branch, cloning only pulled 70 MB

Comment: @Joe OK. That's odd. I'm guessing that something else happened there unrelated to Azure DevOps, since "The history window remained the same" isn't possible with a proper hard reset to an older commit, locally. Regardless, I'm glad this is resolved. ;)

Comment: @Joe Regarding this, "remote repo *did* get reduced in size... I know this because... cloning only pulled 70 MB". AFIAK Azure DevOps never deletes any commits once you pushed them. Those commits would be orphaned on the remote server only, and therefore clones won't see them. Again, this doesn't matter much from the user's perspective except to know this is the case. (e.g. if a plain text password was pushed, it might matter to know it's never truly deleted off the server.) cont...

Comment: @Joe cont... If I'm right I believe this should be easy to prove: go to the previous PR (probably abandoned by now) and click on the commit, and you should see the huge file still there, and you could still even download it if you wanted to. If you really liked that commit, on the right side you can click on the 3 dots menu and create a branch from that commit. As soon as you do that it would start appearing in fetches and clones again. This is how you can "revive" old orphaned commits if you know their commit hash, in case you ever need to do that.

Comment: I see.  Yes I can see it there in the abandoned PR.  I guess that's OK.  If Microsoft wants to keep that 2GB file around that's up to them.  As long as a fresh clone the repo doesn't need to pull it, it's all the same to us:   Azure DevOps does not charge us by the sizes of our repos, only by what we put into artifiacts/feeds.  So for all our purposes, I think we are good